# cannot decode array element (encoded as string) recieved via socket

Tags: python, sockets

I was writing a program to send a directory of contents to the client side via socket. A part of the program deals with making an array with a certain code (ex: code 1 means client should expect a file name, 2 means client should expect file content) and the other deals with decoding this array. But while decoding using .decode() method, i get

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

I'm new to socket programming, but have successfully decoded strings sent via socket what am I doing wrong?

server code:

```
   cab=['1'.encode,c.encode()] #since file is not created, file name 'c'  is sent
   client.send(pickle.dumps(cab)) #transmits the cab
```

client code:

```
cab=pickle.loads(client.recv(r_size))
if(cab):
    d=cab[0]
    print(d.decode())
    return 0
else:
    print("error")
```

Comment: Find out by printing d before trying to decode it. Also have a look at [type()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type). Finally, the question isn't really about sockets...

Comment: I did try that, it returned the address of an encoded string.

Comment: It should be a bytes object ([decode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode)). Is that a typo in your server code (missing brackets)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would seem to be the issue:

```
cab=['1'.encode, # <-- no parentheses
     c.encode()]
```

You didn't call the method, you just passed the callable.
Should be:

```
 cab=['1'.encode(),c.encode()]
```